# Excel query issues with dates as column headers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of data I am trying to manipulate. I have a list of dates as column headers, and a list of names as row headers, the data in the middle is just a list of standard numbers (hrs).

What I would like to do is have something like a pivot table, where I can select a data range, for example, a week, and it will give me the list of names and a sum of their hrs for that date range.

I thought a simple pivot table would work with this however it pulls each date as a single field which would mean pulling all 365 rows or running a new table for every date range.

any ideas would be helpful as I'm struggling to figure out a plan.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your data is already in a pivoted format. You'll need to unpivot it first, then repivot. To unpivot you can use power query or `makeArray()` with `sequence()` and `index()`

Comment: Maybe you need share us with a simple sample.

Comment: A bunch of SUMIF functions would do the job - SUM the cells for each row IF the date on the top row is in the desired ranged (>= RangeStart, <= RangeEnd)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this formula will help.
With the data set out as below the formula in `B14` is

```
=LET(StartCol, MATCH(B3,$A$6:$K$6,0),
           EndCol, MATCH(C3,$A$6:$K$6,0),
           FilteredData,INDEX($A$7:$K$11,,StartCol):INDEX($A$7:$K$11,,EndCol),
           TotalHours, BYROW(FilteredData,LAMBDA(array,SUM(array))),
           HSTACK($A$7:$A$11,TotalHours))
```

[image]